# pandas.DataFrame() AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_ndarray_values'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

A rather perplexing error I have only just started to get when trying to generate empty dataframes with column names called.

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.__version__
Out: '1.0.1'

allGeneLen = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Sample", "geneLength"])

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-243-4783cb8742c4>", line 1, in <module>
    allGeneLen = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Sample", "geneLength"])

  File "C:\Users\wmn262\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}

  File "C:\Users\wmn262\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 228, in init_dict
    make_block(dvals_list[n], placement=[n], ndim=2)

  File "C:\Users\wmn262\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__

  File "C:\Users\wmn262\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    The other object to compare against.

  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__

  File "C:\Users\wmn262\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 608, in _engine
    The array interface, return my values.

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_ndarray_values'
```

I have no idea why this is happening and as far as i understand it should not be happening.
Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Added to question. v1.0.1

Comment: Kindly upgrade your pandas version as `allGeneLen = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Sample", "geneLength"])` working fine in `pandas 1.2.0`

Comment: @AnuragDabas This has solved it thank you. However this exact bit of code was working earlier today. What would cause it to not work in 1.0.1?

Comment: This definitely looks like a regression (bug). Not sure if it's worth opening a ticket for since this looks solved on later version and on pandas master.